# Bootstrap bug - input has-error has-feedback glyphicon not vertically centred?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Why `glyphicon-warning-sign form-control-feedback` is not vertically centred in the code below - after adding `font-size: 20px;` to the `label`?

```
<div class="container">

      <div class="content align-left contact">
        <p>Hello World!</p>
        <form action="#" method="post" id="contact-form">

          <div class="form-group has-error has-feedback">
            <label for="inputName">Your Name (required)</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="input-name" placeholder="Name">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span id="inputWarning2Status">(warning)</span>
          </div>

        </form>
      </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.has-feedback .form-control-feedback {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.content {
  padding: 100px;
}
.content p {
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.content.contact label {
  font-weight: 700;
}
.content.contact label {
  font-size: 20px; // this is where the error cause - but why!???
}
```

Result:

[image]

The warning text is not red too.

Any ideas?

at [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pvceqywp/) but I can't find bootstrap as the load option!

**EDIT:**

You can see the bug at [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/qlBJmx0ZZv)

Comment: You should use bootply (not jsfiddle) for bootstrap examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brad's answer is good, but it is partial. When you change size of the label, or you put some more content before input, then it will be destroyed again. Since element `.form-control-feedback` has absolute position, then you should warp it in the common parent with input, so you will always get the right result. Add this CSS:

```
.warning {
  color:#a94442;
}
.my-group {
  position: relative;
}
```

And update you HTML:

```
<div class="form-group has-error has-feedback">
    <label for="inputName">Your Name (required)</label>
    <div class="my-group">
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="input-name" placeholder="Name">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </div>
    <span id="inputWarning2Status">(warning)</span>
</div>
```

Working demo: http://www.bootply.com/jGxRAFMKkg

Comment: I like this solution without hacking bootstrap! thanks!

Comment: Yea, no-hacking solutions are always the best :) You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

1) you can add external resources to jsfiddle on the left side of the screen, use the bootstrap CDN.

2) the font-size for the label is causing the problem. The icon is fixed and doesnt play nice with the label size changing (don't ask me why - log with bootstrap).

3) THE FIX: add the following to css:

```
.has-feedback label~.form-control-feedback {
  top:33px;
}
.warning {
  color:#a94442; /*add this class to your warnings span*/
}
```

DEMO https://jsfiddle.net/10yLhpu3/

Comment: the increase in the font-size was pushing the input box down. the total being 33px. I think by default bootstrap do top:20px; or something like that, so if you increase the font-size more you would also need to increase the top:33px; accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Add this to you stylesheet:

```
.glyphicon-warning-sign{
  margin-top:8px;
  }

  #inputWarning2Status{
  color:red;
  }
```

http://www.bootply.com/gy41ldchWf

And it will work fine.

Answer (score -1):

Remove this from the style

`.content.contact label {
  font-size: 20px; 
}`

In this line of code add warning in the class

`<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign form-control-feedback warning" aria-hidden="true"></span>`

add any class name then replace the style that you've remove with this

`.warning {
     font-size: 20px;
}`